# Issue with Tables and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to tags that are nested in a tr tag, but the identifier that I'm using to find the correct value is nested in another td within the tr tag.

That is, I'm using the website [LoLKing](http://lolking.net/champions)

And trying to scrape it for statistics based on a name, for example, Ahri.

The HTML is:

```
<tr>
            <td data-sorttype="string" data-sortval="Ahri" style="text-align: left;">
                <div style="display: table-cell;">
                <div class="champion-list-icon" style="background:url(//lkimg.zamimg.com/shared/riot/images/champions/103_32.png)">
                    <a style="display: inline-block; width: 28px; height: 28px;" href="/champions/ahri"></a>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; padding-top: 3px; padding-left: 5px;"><a href="/champions/ahri">Ahri</a></div>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"  data-sortval="975"><img src='//lkimg.zamimg.com/images/rp_logo.png' width='18' class='champion-price-icon'>975</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;" data-sortval="6300"><img src='//lkimg.zamimg.com/images/ip_logo.png' width='18' class='champion-price-icon'>6300</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;" data-sortval="10.98">10.98%</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;" data-sortval="48.44">48.44%</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;" data-sortval="18.85">18.85%</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;" data-sorttype="string" data-sortval="Middle Lane">Middle Lane</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;" data-sortval="1323849600">12/14/2011</td>
        </tr>
```

I'm having problems extracting the statistics, which are nested in td tags outside of the data-sortval. I imagine that I want to pull ALL the tr tags, but I don't know how to pull the tr tag based off of the one that contains the td tag with data-sortval="Ahri". At that point, I would want to step through the tr tag x times until I reach the first statistic I want, 10.98

At the moment, I'm trying to do a find for the td with data-sortval Ahri, but it doesn't return the rest of the tr.

It might be important to not that all of this is nested inside if a larger tag:

```
  <table class="clientsort champion-list" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
    <tr><th>Champion</th><th>RP Cost</th><th>IP Cost</th><th>Popularity</th><th>Win Rate</th><th>Ban Rate</th><th>Meta</th><th>Released</th></tr>     
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

I apologize for the lack of clarity, I'm new with this scraping terminology, but I hope that makes enough sense.
Right now, I'm also doing:

```
main = soup.find('table', {'class':'clientsort champion-list'})
```

To get only that table

edit:

I typed this for the variable:

```
for champ in champs:
    a = str(champ)
    print type(a) is str
    td_name = soup.find('td',{"data-sortval":a})
```

It confirms that a is a string.
But it throws this error:

```
  File "lolrec.py", line 82, in StatScrape
    tr = td_name.parent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GO LOL!

***For commercial purpose, please read the terms of services before scraping.***

(1) To scrape a list of heroes, you can do this, which follows a similar logic as you described.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
html = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.lolking.net/champions/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
# locate the cell that contains hero name: Ahri 
hero_list = ["Blitzcrank", "Ahri", "Akali"]
for hero in hero_list:
    td_name = soup.find('td', {"data-sortval":hero})
    tr = td_name.parent
    popularity = tr.find_all('td', recursive=False)[3].text
    print hero, popularity
```

Output

```
Blitzcrank 12.58%
Ahri 10.98%
Akali 7.52%
```

Output

```
10.98%
```

(2) To scrape all the heroes.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
html = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.lolking.net/champions/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
# find the table first
table = soup.find('table', {"class":"clientsort champion-list"})
# find the all the rows
for row in table.find('tbody').find_all("tr", recursive=False):
    cols = row.find_all("td")
    hero = cols[0].text.strip()
    popularity = cols[3].text
    print hero, popularity
```

Output:

```
Aatrox 6.86%
Ahri 10.98%
Akali 7.52%
Alistar 4.9%
Amumu 8.75%
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
This is actually for research purposes, as I'm a student researcher at my university.

I hope to release it for free if that's possible, but I'll definitely do what you recommended and read the terms of services.

Comment: I have a question, though. How would I manage to change
soup.find('td', {"data-sortval":"Ahri"})
to use a variable in place of "Ahri", let's say all the keys of a dictionary? At the moment, I'm casting the keys as strings and then trying to pass them in a for loop, but it seems like find won't take variable headers

Comment: soup.find("td", {"data-sortval":variable})

Comment: You see, that was my intuition, so I did the changes ( see edited post ) and it throws an error (see edited post)

Comment: Disregard, I figured it out. The string on the website has punctuation, the string from my data structure does not. This poses an interesting problem. Thank you for your help!